# "error: too many #pragma options align=reset" on mac with gcc 4.8

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, pragma, libusb

I used macports to update gcc to version 4.8.1. I would like to use that version to build libusbx 1.0.17. But when I './configure' and then 'make' libusbx I get "error: too many #pragma options align=reset" (see error bellow), and it fails to build. If I configure libusbx with 'CC=clang ./configure' and then 'make' it works fine but that is building with gcc 4.2, and that is not what I want. Is there any way to build libusbx with gcc 4.8 on mac? Thanks

```
make  all-recursive
Making all in libusb
  CC       libusb_1_0_la-core.lo
  CC       libusb_1_0_la-descriptor.lo
  CC       libusb_1_0_la-io.lo
  CC       libusb_1_0_la-strerror.lo
  CC       libusb_1_0_la-sync.lo
  CC       libusb_1_0_la-hotplug.lo
  CC       os/libusb_1_0_la-threads_posix.lo
  CC       os/libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.lo
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Headers/usb/IOUSBLib.h:27:0,
                 from os/darwin_usb.h:27,
                 from os/darwin_usb.c:43:
/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Headers/usb/USB.h:576:9: error: too many #pragma options align=reset
 #pragma options align=reset
         ^
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Headers/usb/IOUSBLib.h:27:0,
                 from os/darwin_usb.h:27,
                 from os/darwin_usb.c:43:
/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Headers/usb/USB.h:746:9: error: too many #pragma options align=reset
 #pragma options align=reset
         ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Headers/usb/USB.h:797:9: error: too many #pragma options align=reset
 #pragma options align=reset
         ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Headers/usb/USB.h:815:9: error: too many #pragma options align=reset
 #pragma options align=reset
         ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Headers/usb/USB.h:835:9: error: too many #pragma options align=reset
 #pragma options align=reset
         ^
os/darwin_usb.c: In function 'darwin_get_device_descriptor':
os/darwin_usb.c:58:76: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
 #define DARWIN_CACHED_DEVICE(a) ((struct darwin_cached_device *) (((struct darwin_device_priv *)((a)->os_priv))->dev))
                                                                            ^
[...]'
```

In USB.h file the pragma's seem to be in this form.

```
#pragma pack(1)
... struct ....
#pragma options align=reset
```

What is the equivalent that works with gcc 4.8? They all seem to be paired correctly, so the issue must be that gcc 4.8 does not understand one or the other.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it to compile by changing all the lines 
in file /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Headers/usb/USB.h with

```
"#pragma options align=reset"
```

to

```
"#ifdef __clang__
    #pragma options align=reset
#else
    #pragma pack()
#endif"
```

Comment: I can confirm this worked.  Is there any chance this would ever be accepted as a patch / included as a fix by mac?